# How I can put a option "Show all" in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report and I don't know how put a option `Show all` in the report.

So, I use *drilldown* for show the products of the clients e I want a option to open all of *drilldowns*. Is possible to create this?

Comment: http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html

Comment: Very thank you @Snowlockk